# Ask Area Chair/Editor to reveal one of the reviewers of my paper

Tags: peer-review, conference, etiquette, anonymity

We submitted a paper to a venue and got accepted. The venue is single-blind, reviewers know our names, but we don't know who they are.

During the review process one reviewer made very good suggestions that will potentially lead to another paper.

We would like to collaborate with the reviewer.

Is it okey to email the area chair, to tell the reviewer to contact us? An email similar to:

```
Dear AC,

We are the authors of paper XXX, we liked the discussion with reviewer YYY.
We are considering extending our research and we would like to invite the reviewer. 

Would it be possible to ask the reviewer to contact us?
```

If it's not okey, why?

Answer (score 2):

"invite the reviewer *into a collaboration*"...

Yes, asking the editor to *ask* (not tell) the reviewer is fine under these circumstances, though they may not want to do it. The two of them can make a decision. But the connection should come from the reviewer, not the editor, which you seem to know.

Comment: I dont know who is the Area Chair/Editor, but I can contact them via email.

Comment: For a conference it is probably the "program chair". For a journal, whoever you last communicated with about acceptance.